# Use Perl to extract all possible substrings

Tags: perl, substring

```
$str="abcde"
```

and i want output array as

```
a,b,c,d,e,ab,bc,cd,de,abc,bcd,cde,abcd,bcde,abcde.
```

ie moving from left to right, all possible combinations of all different lengths.

Also, additional function to remove duplicate elements, like

```
$str="abcdd"
```

may have many duplicate items in array

This is what I have tried

```
for ($j=1;$j<=$n;$j++) {
   my @tmp = unpack("(A$j)*", $seq);
   print "@tmp\n";
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: for($j=1;$j<=$n;$j++)
    {
    my @tmp = unpack("(A$j)*", $seq);
    print "@tmp\n";
    }

Answer (score 3):

This is an extremely simple problem. This program solves it in a single line, although a double loop would probably be clearer.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $str = 'abcde';

my @list;

push @list, $str =~ /(?=(.{$_}))/g for 1 .. length $str;

say join ',', @list;
```

**output**

```
a,b,c,d,e,ab,bc,cd,de,abc,bcd,cde,abcd,bcde,abcde
```

Comment: how to avoid duplicate, like for string aacde, i do not want a, a to appear twice in @list

Answer (score 1):

The only trick to this problem is knowing that one needs to use a [Positive lookahead assertion](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) in order to find regular expression matches that overlap.

If you then only want unique substrings, then either read [perlfaq4 - How can I remove duplicate elements from a list or array?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-remove-duplicate-elements-from-a-list-or-array%3f) or use [`List::MoreUtils uniq`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);

for my $string (qw(abcde abcdd)) {
    my @list = uniq map { $string =~ /(?=(.{$_}))/g } ( 1 .. length $string );
    print "$string - ", join( ',', @list ), "\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
abcde - a,b,c,d,e,ab,bc,cd,de,abc,bcd,cde,abcd,bcde,abcde
abcdd - a,b,c,d,ab,bc,cd,dd,abc,bcd,cdd,abcd,bcdd,abcdd
```