# getting every possible substring in perl

Tags: perl, substring

I would like to generate every possible consecutive substring of a string, including the end of the word/beginning from the word (cyclic) letter combinations. I've found an example in Python, but the only language I know is perl (and barely, I'm a beginner). I would appreciate it a lot if someone can help me translating the code to perl or to help me find a solution in perl.

the code is the following:

```
 aa='ABCD'

 F=[]

 B=[]

 for j in range(1,len(aa)+1,1):

for i in range(0,len(aa),1):

    A=str.split(((aa*j)[i:i+j]))

    B=B+A

    C=(B[0:len(aa)*len(aa)-len(aa)+1])
```

it gives you:

C=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'DA', 'ABC', 'BCD', 'CDA', 'DAB', 'ABCD']`

Comment: It would probably be easier to write that logic from scratch if you know Perl.

Comment: Why aren't `BCDA`, `CDAB`, and `DABC` returned, too?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25887202/use-perl-to-extract-all-possible-substrings

Comment: I really don't know, the problem is that I don't understand the functions of the example. In the end I really don't need "ABCD" or any other four-letter combinations, I need only the substrings.

Comment: stevieb: i checked it but i need the cyclic substrings. end/begin of the string.

Comment: And they say Perl is line noise!

Comment: I like Perl a lot because is really explicit. I need step-by-step explanations :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my $string = 'ABCD';

my @substrings;
for my $length (1 .. length $string) {
    for my $pos (0 .. length($string) - 1) {
        push @substrings, substr $string x 2, $pos, $length;
    }
}

say for @substrings;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in using a pre-built solution, you could checkout [the CPAN](http://searc.cpan.org), where I found the module `String::Substrings`.  Because you want "wrap-around" substrings and want to eliminate the "substrings" that have the same length as the actual string, you'll have to do a little manipulation:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use String::Substrings;
use feature 'say';

my $string = 'ABCD';
my %substrs;
for my $len (1..length($string)-1) {
   $substrs{$_}++ for substrings("$string"x2, $len);
}
say for sort keys %substrs;
```

Results:

```
A
AB
ABC
B
BC
BCD
C
CD
CDA
D
DA
DAB
```

Comment: Thank you :)  I'll check it out.